# Setting a cookie with sessionOnly:False

Tags: swift, http, cookies

Is there a way to manually set cookies in Swift that don't expire at the end of a session? [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpcookiepropertykey/1393001-discard) say that `sessionOnly` should default to false and can be set using the `discard` property, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I've tried:

```
import Foundation


let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
    .domain: ".google.com",
    .path: "/",
    .name: "foo",
    .value: "bar",
    .discard: "FALSE"
])!


HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)

let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)

print(cookies)
// Optional([<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"foo" value:"bar" expiresDate:(null) created:2016-11-23 16:00:37 +0000 sessionOnly:TRUE domain:".google.com" partition:"none" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>])
```

but as shown, the resulting cookie has a `sessionOnly` value of true.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score -1):

(static let discard: HTTPCookiePropertyKey = "FALSE") should work based on the Apple documentation.